# number of solutions to $x^2+y^2=r$

Tags: number-theory

I know how to find number of solutions to $x^2+y^2=1$ which we denote be $N(x^2+y^2=1)$. It is equal to $p-1$ or $p+1$ according to $p\equiv1(4)$ or $p\equiv3(4)$using approach of characters and jacobi sums given in Rosen and Ireland. but i was thinking if we want to find $N(x^2+y^2=r)$ for some integer r.

as jacobi sums are defined as $\sum\chi(a)\rho(b)$ where $a+b=1$ so do we need to change this condition to $a+b=r$? but then it might not follow jacobi sum's properties.
please suggest the right way using this approach.

I know when it is solvable as the theorem in montgomery's book that only if all the prime factors of $r$ are of the form $4k+1$ and 2 can have power atmost 1 in prime factorisation. but i am think on finding number of solution when it is solvable.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html